# Writing the Euler-Lagrange equation for variation of an action with respect to metric using only the Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, action, variational-calculus

Given Lagrangian which dependent on collection of fields ${\phi^a},a=1,...,N$
and on a tensor metric $g^{\mu\nu}$ such that the action in $d$ dimension which describes the system is $$S=\int d^dx \sqrt{-g}\mathscr{L}[\phi^a,g^{\mu\nu}].\tag{1}$$

I know That variation of such general action with respect to  the metric gives rise to the following Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$ \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\alpha\beta}}=0 \iff \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial g^{\alpha\beta}}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\alpha\beta}\mathscr{L}=T_{\alpha\beta}\tag{2}$$

Where $T_{\alpha\beta}$ is the stress-energy tensor.

On the other hand, there is a general expression for the stress-energy tensor given a Lagrangian:
$$T_{\alpha\beta}=\sum_a{\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial{(\partial_{\alpha}\phi^a)}}\partial_{\beta}\phi^a}-g_{\alpha\beta}\mathscr{L}\tag{3}$$

combining both equations above, we get the Euler-Lagrange equation expressed only through the Lagrangian and its derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial g^{\alpha\beta}}-\sum_a{\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial{(\partial_{\alpha}\phi^a)}}\partial_{\beta}\phi^a}+\frac{1}{2}g_{\alpha\beta}\mathscr{L}=0.\tag{4}$$

Is this a correct formula? because I didn't see this formula in any place.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Eq. (2) does not seem right: $T$ appears only in one of the 2 equations.

Comment: @Qmechanic So what is the correct Euler Lagrange equation at Eq .(2)?

Comment: My guess would be that this is incorrect: As far as I am aware, as the version presented in equation $(3)$ is derived under the assumption that only the field depends on position i.e. the theory is not coupled to gravity as in such a scenario eq. (3) should include a term corresponding to the variation of the integration measure as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula (3) defines the *canonical energy-momentum tensor* of the field, which is defined only in flat Minkowski spacetime and is the Noether current associated to *translation symmetry*.

By contrast, formula (2) defines the *Einstein-Hilbert energy momentum tensor*, which is also defined in a general spacetime background, but is not a Noether current, at least not in the sense the canonical tensor is.

It is well-known that the canonical EM tensor often requires "improvement", whereas it is generally accepted that the Einstein-Hilbert EM tensor is the "correct" EM tensor of a given field.

Formula (4) would be valid if the EHEM tensor (Einstein-Hilbert energy momentum tensor) and the CEM tensor (canonical energy-momentum tensor) turned out to be always equivalent to one another. This is not true in general however.

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0307199) by Forger and Römer examines the relationship between these two tensors in great detail.

I will give a simpler analysis here. Suppose that the Lagrangian is $\mathcal L(\phi,\partial\phi,g)$ (the factor of $\sqrt{|\mathfrak g|}$ is considered part of the Lagrangian) and the field theory has some concept of diffeomorphism symmetry and the Lagrangian is diffeomorphism invariant. The Lie derivative of the $\phi=(\phi^i)$ field is written generally as $$ \delta_X\phi^i=X^\mu\phi^i_{,\mu}+Q^{i,\mu}{}_\nu(\phi,\partial\phi)X^\nu_{,\mu} $$for any vector field $X^\mu$. (For fields which are not in the representation of the diffeomorphism group, see the paper by Forger and Römer).

Under a diffeomorphism, the Lagrangian is a scalar density, thus $$ \delta_X\mathcal L=\partial_\mu(X^\mu\mathcal L)=\frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{T}^{\mu\nu}\delta_X g_{\mu\nu}+E_i\delta_X\phi^i+\partial_\mu(P^\mu_i\delta_X\phi^i), $$
where $$ \mathfrak T^{\mu\nu}:=2\frac{\delta \mathcal L}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}},\quad E_i =\frac{\delta\mathcal L}{\delta\phi^i},\quad P^\mu_i=\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\phi^i_{,\mu}},$$and finally, $\delta_Xg_{\mu\nu}=2\nabla_{[\mu}X_{\nu]}$ is the metric Lie derivative.

If we expand the Lie derivatives and integrate by parts on the vector field $X$ and rearrange the terms to $0$, we get $$ 0=[E_i\phi^i_{,\nu}-\partial_\mu(E_i Q^{i,\mu}{}_\nu)-\nabla_\mu\mathfrak T^{\mu}{}_\nu]X^\nu+\partial_\mu[\mathfrak T^\mu{}_\nu X^\nu+P^\mu_i\delta_X\phi^i+E_iQ^{i,\mu}{}_\nu X^\nu]. $$

If we integrate this and take $X^\mu$ to be compactly supported, we get that the first bracket $[...]$ must vanish identically. This gives $$ \nabla_\mu\mathfrak T^\mu{}_\nu=E_i\phi^i_{,\nu}-\partial_\mu(E_iQ^{i,\mu}{}_\nu) $$as an off-shell relation. If the field $\phi$ is on-shell, then this reduces to $\nabla_\mu\mathfrak T^\mu{}_\nu=0$. Let the vector density whose total divergence appears in the second bracket $\partial_\mu[...]$ be denoted $S^\mu_X$.

Then we also get that $\partial_\mu S^\mu_X=0$ for all possible choices of $X$ and $\phi$ and $g$. If we expand the Lie derivative in $S^\mu_X$ as well, we get $$S^\mu_X=(\mathfrak T^\mu{}_\nu+P^\mu_i\phi^i_{,\nu}-\mathcal L\delta^\mu_\nu+E_iQ^{i,\mu}{}_\nu)X^\nu+P^\mu_iQ^{i,\kappa}{}_\nu X^\nu_{,\kappa}. $$ It is then fairly easy to show that $\partial_\mu S^\mu_X=0$ for all choices of $X^\mu$ implies that $$ S^\mu_X=\partial_\rho K^{\mu\rho}_X,\quad K^{\mu\rho}_X=P^{[\mu}_i Q^{i,\rho]}{}_\nu X^\nu, $$ so $K^{\mu\rho}_X$ is skew-symmetric in $\mu\rho$, moreover $K^{\mu\rho}_X$ is *unique* (the higher order analogue of this proof is much more difficult and the uniqueness is lost!).

Now evaluate this entire relation ($S^\mu_X=\partial_\rho K^{\mu\rho}_X$) in *flat spacetime* with $X^\mu=\tau^\mu$ a constant translation vector! Moreover, evaluate it on-shell for the $\phi$ field, i.e. $E_i=0$. Then we get $$ S^\mu=(T^\mu{}_\nu+P^\mu_i\phi^i_{,\nu}-\mathcal L\delta^\mu_\nu)\tau^\nu=\partial_\rho(P^{[\mu}_i Q^{i,\rho]}{}_\nu)\tau^\nu, $$ and using that $\tau$ is *any* constant vector field, we get $$ T^\mu{}_\nu=\mathcal L\delta^\mu_\nu-P^\mu_i\phi^i_{,\nu}+\partial_\rho(P^{[\mu}_i Q^{i,\rho]}{}_\nu). $$

Here $T^\mu{}_\nu$ is the (flat spacetime limit of the) Einstein-Hilbert energy momentum tensor, the $\Theta^\mu{}_\nu:=\mathcal L\delta^\mu_\nu-P^\mu_i\phi^i_{,\nu}$ is the canonical energy momentum tensor, and the divergence terms are correction terms.

This is the correct relation at least under the assumptions made on the initial form of the Lagrangian.